# how to write each loop for has_many in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

employee has many skills
skill belongs_to employee
[image: has_many]

Skills table have employee_id(foreign key).

I want to display in view

Comment: You need to be more specific than this. SO is not a place to help you write your code, but to answer specific questions. If you are unaware how to create a view, please do a basic rails totorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: Are you showing multiple skills of one employee in view table or multiple employee with their multiple skills ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ways to get the collections of users.

1. @employees = Employee.all.joins(:skills)
2. @employees = Employee.all.includes(:skills)
3. @employees = Employee.all.eager_load(:skills)

In your view add below code in HTML/HAML/SLIM file.

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= employee.name %></td>
    <td><%= employee.skills.map(&:title).join(", ") %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>`
```

Comment: It is good idea to explain difference between these 3 methods

Comment: You don't need to join the skills when they are already defined as an association.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Employee </th>
   <th>Skills</th>
  </tr>
  <% @employees.each do |employee|%>
    <tr>
       <td><%= employee.name %></td>     
       <td><%= employee.skills.map(&:name).join(', ') %></td>     
    </tr>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

This above code will list all skill names of each employee.
You can read a complete guide [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with something like this.
In `controller` return all the `employees`
so it will be like

```
@employees = Employee.all.includes(:skills)
```

and in the `view` you can do

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <tr>
     <td><%= employee.name %></td>
     <td><%= employee.skills.collect(&:title).join(", ") %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in this case is to write an instance method on your `Employee` class:

```rb
class Employee < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :skills

  def skills_list
    skills.pluck(:title).join(', ')
  end
end
```

And use it like this in your view:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @employee.id %></td>
    <td><%= @employee.name %></td>
    <td><%= @employee.skills_list %></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This guy plucks. This should be the accepted answer OP.